# How to compare two query results for equality in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, comparison, subquery

I'm a MySQL user. I have two queries, and I wish to **compare their results for equality**. I would like to do this with a single query which would return true or false, so each of my two queries would most likely take the form of sub-queries.

I would like to avoid returning the results from both queries and comparing them at the application level, to cut down on communication and to improve performance. I would also like to avoid looping over the results at the database level if possile, but if there's no other way, so be it.

I have searched high and low for an example on how to do this, but have come up empty handed. Some **sample code** would be most appreciated, because I'm a newbie to SQL programming. Thanks!

**Note:** I'm looking for a solution which would work with any two arbitrary queries, so I'm going to refrain from posting what my two queries happen to be.

Comment: If you provide us with what you've already got, someone might be able to help you.

Comment: I have nothing. Like I said in the post, I have come up empty handed

Comment: Perhaps provide your database schema and what data you're looking to retrieve - there may be a better alternative.

Comment: Are you limited to `MySQL`?  This would be trivial in `SQL Server`

Comment: does order/duplicates matter?

Comment: One trivial solution might be to use `EXPLAIN` and compare the query plans.  don't know if that applies to your particular situation.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: EXPLAIN produces the EXPLAIN plan; the OP wants to diff the result set

Comment: @JNK: Yep, yet another case of ANSI syntax (`EXCEPT`) that MySQL needs to implement :/  Oracle's had `MINUS` for a while...

Answer (score 21):

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN count1 = count2 AND count1 = count3 THEN 'identical' ELSE 'mis-matched' END
FROM
(
  SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <query1>) AS count1,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM <query2>) AS count2,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM query1 UNION SELECT * FROM query2) AS unioned) AS count3
)
  AS counts
```

Comment: +1 nice and simple. Of course it has the same problems as mine with dups and order

Comment: perhaps if you went with UNION ALL and did `WHEN Count1 = count2 AND (Count1 *2)  = Count3` you wouldn't have the Dupe problem

Comment: The logic *only* works because of UNION not including duplicates.  Otherwise it is only checking the relative number of records, not the contents.

Comment: @MatBailie Does this tell me that both query 1 and query 2 return me the same result set (I mean the same number of records where each record of `query1` has a same record of `query 2` and the fields of the record has the same value)? Of course, the order is not taken into consideration here.

Comment: This works well when the query is relatively simple and there aren't a ton of mixed joins, but how can someone be sure that some columns aren't now null, where there were values before?

Comment: @Urasquirrel - The UNION in count3 takes care as that.  A value changing from NULL to NOT NULL (in one row) would cause the UNION to have one more row than the two independent sets (count1 and count2).

Answer (score 4):

This would be a little easier if MySQL supported `FULL OUTER JOIN` also note that if the the two queries give the same results but in different order that will be deemed equivlant

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) 
FROM 
(
    (SELECT A, b, c FROM A) a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
      (SELECT A, b, c FROM b) B
    ON A.a = b.a and a.b = b.b and a.c = b.c
UNION 
    (SELECT A, b, c FROM A) a
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
   (SELECT A, b, c FROM b) B
    ON A.a = b.a and a.b = b.b and a.c = b.c
) 
WHERE a.a is null or b.a is null
```

If the count =0 then the two queries are the same

Also because I'm using UNION duplicates are being removed. So there's a potential inaccuracy there.

Comment: Could the inaccuracy be solved by using UNION ALL instead of UNION to preserve the duplicates?

Comment: This isn't truly universal though since you need to alter the `JOIN` and `WHERE` clauses every time the inner queries change.

Comment: @JNK hmm so the comment is "the query will change every time the query changes" good to know ;) I suppose Dems solution requires fewer changes but its no more universal.

Comment: @Conrad - sorry to be unclear, just noticed OP asked for something as generic as possible.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do MINUS in MySQL, so here's how to do it without:

```
select if(count(*)=0,'same','different') from (
select col1,col2,col3
from tableone
where ( col1, col2, col3 ) not in
( select col4, col5, col6
  from tabletwo )
union
select col4, col5, col6
from tabletwo
where ( col4, col5, col6 ) not in
( select col1, col2, col3
  from tableone )
) minusintersec;
```

That's given:

```
tableone (col1 integer, col2 integer, col3 integer );

tabletwo (col4 integer, col5 integer, col6 integer );
```